# Condensing Code with For Loop?

Tags: vba, excel

So I am creating a module to find a text string in a sheet to print into another sheet, the code works But it feels cumbersome, i have to run the code multiple times to get the results I want, i know a For statement is how i should be going about it but I just wanted to check. This is the current code

```
Sub FindRANumbers()
Dim RA1Range As Range
emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheet3.Range("A:A")) + 1
Sheet2emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheet2.Range("H:H"))

'Find Checkbox values and paste them into Sheet 3
Set RA1Range = Sheet2.Cells.Find("RA0001")
Set RA1Check = Sheet3.Cells.Find("RA0001")
If Not RA1Check Is Nothing Then

ElseIf Not RA1Range Is Nothing Then
    Sheet3.Cells(emptyRow, 1).MergeArea.Value = "RA0001"
End If

End Sub
```

It needs to loop through as many rows as are in Sheet2 H:H.

I am not very well versed in For loops but when I this, I still need to run the code multiple times

```
For i = 1 To Sheet2emptyrow
'Above code here'
Next i
```

I feel like i am missing something quite simple

Thank you in advance for any help.

EDIT:

I think my description of the problem is a little poor so I have attached an Image to show what i am trying to do [image: Screenshot of sheet 2]
So I want to loop through as many cells that are filled here in Sheet 2 and run my code for each loop

I hope that makes more sense? Sorry about this, But thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the example of [Range.Find Method (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-find-method-excel) this code finds with a For Loop.

> However, remember that if you are working with a large Workbook, it is not the fastest way of searching. Here is a [performance test](https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/10/26/match-vs-find-vs-variant-array-vba-performance-shootout/)

And do you really have to search on the entire Sheet3? Because it makes it really sloooow. Assuming Sheet2 Column H are the reference values, so you search it on the entire Sheet3.

```
lastrow = Sheet2.Cells(Sheet2.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row
For I = 8 To lastrow
   Set c = Sheet2.Cells(I, 8)
   With Sheet3
       Set cellFound = .Find(what:=c, LookIn:=xlValues, MatchCase:=False)
           If Not cellFound Is Nothing Then
               FirstAddress = cellFound.Address
               Do
                   'When value is found do something here
                   Debug.Print cellFound.Address 'To print the addresses of cells found
                   Set cellFound = .FindNext(cellFound)
               Loop While Not cellFound Is Nothing And cellFound.Address <> FirstAddress
            End If
   End With
 Next I
```

### Exaplaining the code

#### LastRow of Column H

`lastrow = Sheet2.Cells(Sheet2.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row`

#### For loop from line 8 to lastrow of column H of Sheet2

```
For I = 8 To lastrow
Next I
```

#### The value to search, so using the variable I to loop through all rows

```
Set c = Sheet2.Cells(I, 8)
```

#### Range of search

```
With Sheet3
End With
```

#### Find, using the example of [.Find Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-find-method-excel)

```
           Set cellFound = .Find(what:=c, LookIn:=xlValues, MatchCase:=False)
           If Not cellFound Is Nothing Then
               FirstAddress = cellFound.Address
               Do
                   'When value is found do something here
                   Debug.Print cellFound.Address 'To print the addresses of cells found
                   Set cellFound = .FindNext(cellFound)
               Loop While Not cellFound Is Nothing And cellFound.Address <> FirstAddress
            End If
```

Comment: I am still struggling with this one, when i try to run this code it states 'Member or Data not found' in relation to the .Find

I assumed it needed a range so tried c.find but this didn't seem to work for me.

Comment: The range is Sheet3, `c` is the String you are searching for, so `RA0001`. And the error can occur due to merged cells, so when using VBA try to avoid merging.

Comment: Ah once again another mountain because of merging cells haha, I have definitely learned that lesson from this project.

Is there a way to side step this or will i need to reformat both sheets?

Comment: There are ways to unmerge, however, it is only woth for really huge workbooks, because it will depend on the logic you are using.

Comment: Thank you this was very helpful and helped me get to what I needed to do. This is my lesson in not using merged cells when i intend to use VBA, haha